# Switch from a UIViewController with tab bar to simple UiViewController

Tags: ios

I've an application with 5 tab items managed by an UITabController. When I click to one tab i want to cal another UIViewController but with hidden tab bar and then (after something ) come back to the previous controller.

How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use a modal view controller

```
UIViewController subclass
<className> *variableName = [[<className> alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:<className> animated:YES];
```

This will create a new window that appears over the current window, and when you want to leave the modal view controller, and go back to the tab bar controller window, just use

```
// check on this one
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and that should help you

P.S: className above is the name of the second view controller you want to appear

Comment: thank you for your reply. But where i have to implement the first part? Into my tab controller? In which method?

Comment: the UIViewController subclass part is just a reminder to make sure your class is a subclass of the UIViewController, but how are you wanting to open this new window? by pressing the tab? button on the screen?

Comment: i open this window by pressing the tab

Comment: ok, well wherever the part for opening the tabs are, put the code in that section.

Comment: @user2277872, you should call that method from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the tab you're selecting. If you call it with an animated argument of NO, it will be the first thing the user see when they click that tab. But you should use the newer methods, the ones in this answer are depreciated (presentViewController:animated:completion: and dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)

Comment: but presentModalViewController is deprecated in iOS 6

Comment: i've implemented the method dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion into my controller called from the tab. But after something  how can i  come back to the tab controller? For example by pressing  a button?

Comment: I didn't know it was depreciated. I am not used to working with iOS 6, im used to 4.3